# Full year view calendar?

Tags: jquery, html, calendar, fullcalendar

I need a calendar like fullcalendar, but I need to show all full year at a time for room/place booking. I have uploaded the image also.

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 12,
    showButtonPanel: true
   });
 });
```

I have used this, but the datepicker can't be used for event/booking.

[image: full year calendar]

Answer (score 2):

There is a fork implementing yearview for FullCalendar:

https://github.com/tpruvot/fullcalendar/releases

Answer (score 0):

This is the calendar you are looking for :

http://www.webappers.com/2010/06/08/wdcalendar-jquery-based-google-calendar-clone/

Comment: thanks for this , i have already view this , here we can set full year , its same as fullcalender , but i need some diff like this image

Comment: @YogeshSaroya - did you ever find anything?

Comment: Did you ever find this functionality in a plugin?